# how to do a model Neural network in netlogo

Tags: neural-network, netlogo

i need a help , i want to create a model with netlogo with Neural Network (perceptron) that alows me to take a number as an input and tell if it is Pair or Impair Number from 0 -- 9 thanks for aides guys

question : how can i do it in netlogo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [ask a specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) so that someone can help you.

Comment: Look in the models library that is included with NetLogo. There is one model there called "Artificial Neural Net - Perceptron".